# Multivariate Interpolation Approaches

Tags: multivariable, interpolation

Is there a good, modern treatment covering the various methods of multivariate interpolation, including which methodologies are typically best for particular types of problems? I'm interested in a solid statistical treatment including error estimates under various model assumptions.

An example:

[Shepard's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting)

Say we're sampling from a multivariate normal distribution with unknown parameters. What can we say about the standard error of the interpolated estimates?

I was hoping for a pointer to a general survey addressing similar questions for the various types of multivariate interpolations in common use.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Interpolation involves 3 things: 1) a class of functions to interpolate, e.g. sound, pictures, terrain; 2) grids of known / unknown points, 4 cases regular <-> scattered; and 3) a model of noise added to 1). There are many many interpolation methods for various cases, most ad hoc, not "in common use";
even IDW has variants. Can you describe what you're interpolating ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, no quick answer. There are thick books dedicated to answering this question. Here's a 600-page long example: [Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441929185)